# How do I create a div and give it an ID based on a changing variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a quiz. The user decides how many questions he wants to answer.

A function then takes this number and runs a loop to make an individual question div for each question. The quiz shows a Chinese character and the user has to pick the correct translation.

My code:

```
var fillInQuestion = function() {
    questionDivIdHTML = 'question' + questionNum;

    /****************************************
    How do I make this Div's ID = to questionDivIdHTML?


    // Creates question div
    $('#questionArea').append("<div class='questionDiv'></div>");
    //$('#questionArea:last-child').attr("id", questionDivIdHTML); <-- NOT WORKING


    ***************************************/

    // Sets up a choice bank.
    var choices = [];

    // choices will be chosen from this.
    var tempAnswerSet = allChoices.slice(0);

    //find random item in the database for the question
    var thisQuestion = allQuestions[Math.floor(Math.random() * allQuestions.length)];

    // add that item to choices
    choices.push(thisQuestion);

    // remove item from 'database' so it cannot be used in another question
    allQuestions.splice(allQuestions.indexOf(thisQuestion), 1);

    // remove item from tempAnswer set so it can only be one choice
    tempAnswerSet.splice(tempAnswerSet.indexOf(thisQuestion), 1);

    // add three more items from the database (incorrect items)    
    var i = 3;
    for (i; i > 0; i--) {
        var addChoice = tempAnswerSet[Math.floor(Math.random() * tempAnswerSet.length)];
        choices.push(addChoice);
        // remove the one selected each time so they cant be chosen again
        tempAnswerSet.splice(tempAnswerSet.indexOf(addChoice), 1);
        //console.log("choices length: " + choices.length);
    }
    // shuffle the array
    choices.shuffle();

    // fill in the div with choices.
    $('#questionDivIdHTML').append("Here is an question prompt:" + thisQuestion.english + "   <br>");
    $('questionDivIdHTMLwithHash').append("<input type='radio' name='question<script>questionNum</script>Choice' value='<script>choices[0].hanyu</script>'></input>" + choices[0].hanyu + "<br>");
    $('questionDivIdHTMLwithHash').append("<input type='radio' name='question<script>questionNum</script>Choice' value='<script>choices[1].hanyu</script>'></input> " + choices[1].hanyu + "<br>");
    $('questionDivIdHTMLwithHash').append("<input type='radio' name='question<script>questionNum</script>Choice' value='<script>choices[2].hanyu</script>'></input> " + choices[2].hanyu + "<br>");
    $('questionDivIdHTMLwithHash').append("<input type='radio' name='question<script>questionNum</script>Choice' value='<script>choices[3].hanyu</script>'></input> " + choices[3].hanyu + "<br>");

};

var fillOutQuiz = function() {
    for (questionAmount; questionAmount > 0; questionAmount--) {
        fillInQuestion();
        questionNum += 1;
    }
};
```

I've gotten this code to work, but I broke it, when trying to add the dynamic ID and loop it.

Comment: when you create the div, why dont you concatenate it there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are saying that this portion of code is not working:

```
$('#questionArea').append("<div class='questionDiv'></div>");
$('#questionArea:last-child').attr("id", questionDivIdHTML);
```

Well, it does not work because the `:last-child` pseudo selector is used incorrectly (see below). It should be:

```
$('#questionArea').append("<div class='questionDiv'></div>");
$('#questionArea > :last-child').attr("id", questionDivIdHTML);
```

Or better, you can rearrange your code like this:

```
$("<div class='questionDiv'></div>")
    .attr("id", questionDivIdHTML)
    .appendTo("#questionArea");
```

---

- `#questionArea:last-child` selects an element with id = questionArea which is also the last child of its parent
- `#questionArea > :last-child` selects the last child of an element with id = questionArea